# The followind code is for geo location but it is showing over_query_limit error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to locate the user and tell him nearest doctors to him but the code is showing over_query_limit. I am not able to resolve the problem as I am new to using API's

I have tried using this code but it is again showing the same problem

```
  {% include 'includes/default.html' %}

 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> 
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVZIr_BmEFJTyl7MzSpBS_XpLrBgZEBZg&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
          });
        }
      </script> -->
      <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
       key=AIzaSyAVZIr_BmEFJTyl7MzSpBS_XpLrBgZEBZg&callback=initalize" -->
      async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = Array();
var infos = Array();
function initialize() {
// prepare Geocoder
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
// set initial position (Byculla)
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.4426,78.9865);
var myOptions = { // default map options
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), 
myOptions);
}
// clear overlays function
function clearOverlays() {
if (markers) {
    for (i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    infos = [];
}
}
// clear infos function
function clearInfos() {
if (infos) {
    for (i in infos) {
        if (infos[i].getMap()) {
            infos[i].close();
        }
    }
}
}
// find address function
function findAddress() {
var address = '{{location}}';
// script uses our 'geocoder' in order to find location by address name
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // and, if everything 
is ok
        // we will center map
        var addrLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
        map.setCenter(addrLocation);
        // store current coordinates into hidden variables
        document.getElementById('lat').value = 
results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = 
results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        // and then - add new custom marker
        var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: addrLocation,
            map: map,
            title: results[0].formatted_address,
            icon: 'marker.png' 
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
status);
    }
    findPlaces();
   });
}
// find custom places function
function findPlaces() {
   // prepare variables (filter)
 var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
// prepare request to Places
var request = {
    location: cur_location,
    radius: 2000,
    types: ['hospital','doctor']
};

// send request
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, createMarkers);
}
// create markers (from 'findPlaces' function)
function createMarkers(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
    clearOverlays();
    // and create new markers by search result
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
    }
 } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) 
{
    alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
}
}
// creare single marker function
function createMarker(obj) {
// prepare new Marker object
var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj.geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: obj.name
});
markers.push(mark);
// prepare info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + 
obj.name +
    '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + ' 
       </font>'
       });
       // add event handler to current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
    clearInfos();
    infowindow.open(map,mark);
   });
infos.push(infowindow);
}
// initialization
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
document.getElementById("doctortab").click();


 </script>

</head>
<body  onload="findAddress()">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="position: absolute; top:200px;right:20px 
;height:400px;width:800px">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="18.9682846" />
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="72.8311396" />
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="{{location}}" id="location" 
   name='location'> -->

</body>
```

The expected result is to show the user doctor but it is showing over_query_limit error

Comment: What code? 
Sounds like you have hit a limit/restriction in a third party system - perhaps you have to register/pay?

Comment: And what is unclear about the error message …? You seem to have gone over the amount of allowed requests you are making with whatever service you are using there. So go figure out whether there’s way to increase that amount, maybe via a paid option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google's geolocation system, last time they made more limits to the free users. You just had to pay for higher connection limits or something like that. Anyway, you didnt posted your code.